# Is it possible to infer email statistics with Visitor Activity results from the Pardot API?

Tags: pardot

all -- I'm attempting to integrate with the Pardot API to obtain email campaign statistics.

Of course my original plan was to query data from the email statistics object, but this won't be possible for us due to known limitations around obtaining the email IDs.

As far as I can tell, the API doesn't provide a handy "list" of email IDs -- and even it did, these IDs would have to be passed individually into query URLs. In other words, we can't obtain an "account-level" report of this activity.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/pardot/guide/emails-v4.html#email-statistics

I know it's possible to reference the Visitor Activity object for email IDs -- however we just don't have enough developmental resources to leverage it in this way.

That being said, the Visitor Activity object is much easier for us to access. Plus, it looks like it can return results for all available email IDs and their respective campaigns.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/pardot/guide/visitor-activity-v5.html

As a result, I was wondering if we can infer statistics for events like email sends, deliveries, and opens using the Visitor Activity data. It looks like the data associated with Visitor Activity Type may be useful for this, but it's hard to validate with our test information. Then again, I have hesitations with this approach because it's not specialized for this use.